# Importar datos de AWS a una bd local, ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando AWS como servidor de mi base de datos, y estoy tratando de importar la informacion en una instancia local de mi workbench. Por recomendacion de alguien me dice que puedo pasar la info de manera automatica a travez de un .cmd, así que estoy tratando de importar ese archivo pero me aparece este mensaje de error:

> 10:21:14 Restoring
> C:\PROYECTO-1\AQUASPOT\AMAZON_AWS\copy_migrated_tables.cmd Running:
> mysql.exe
> --defaults-file="c:\users\alecs\appdata\local\temp\tmpauwa6v.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\PROYECTO-1\AQUASPOT\AMAZON_AWS\copy_migrated_tables.cmd" ERROR
> 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'REM Workbench Table Data copy script REM Workbench
> Version: 8.0.22 REM  REM Exec' at line 1
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1 10:21:14 Import of
> C:\PROYECTO-1\AQUASPOT\AMAZON_AWS\copy_migrated_tables.cmd has
> finished with 1 errors

Este es el código

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    camaronera VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    grupo VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    sector VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    administrador VARCHAR(45), 
    cel_administrador CHAR(16), 
    Jefe_de_Campo VARCHAR(45), 
    cel_jefe_campo CHAR(16), 
    contacto VARCHAR(45), 
    cel_contacto VARCHAR(16), 
    cosechadora_adquirida TINYINT, 
    alquiler_cosecha TINYINT, 
    alquiler_transferencia TINYINT,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    );


CREATE TABLE COSECHADORA (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    id_cliente INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    marca VARCHAR(30), 
    marca_motor VARCHAR(30), 
    modelo_motor VARCHAR(30), 
    estado INT, 
    ubicacion VARCHAR(45), 
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTES(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE = innodb;
```

Comment: osea no esta completo por que son algunas tablas, pero lo que estoy tratando de hacer es importar un archivo .cmd que lo cree con la opcion de 'SATART MIGRATION'  y cuando importo ese archivo me sale ese error, entonces pense que habia un error en la Syntax de mi codigo, pero si no es eso a que se refiere.

Comment: Jum, retiro lo dicho. La generación del backup está incluyendo unas líneas a forma de comentario (`REM blablabla`) y la forma como intentas importarlo no logra reconocerlas como tal. Creo que es importante que indiques la instrucción con la que generaste ese backup :)